# Simple bash problem related to executing command after previous has stopped (I am not programmer)

Tags: bash, wine

```
#!/bin/sh
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = equal plus"
cd /media/5F53-7973/BGTrilogy/
wine ./bgmain.exe
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = dead_caron dead_tilde dead_caron dead_tilde notsign notsign"
```

Basically what I want from it is that the last entry would only run after I quit `wine ./bgmain.exe`.

What's the most foolproof way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `wait` on a line after the `wine` command.